# Получить список и изображение всех символов из TTF формата?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Как получить список и изображение (bitmap) всех доступных символов из TTF(True Type Font) формата в зависимости от CharSet (ANSI_CHARSET, RUSSIAN_CHARSET, ...)?

Comment: Какие попытки решения задачи самостоятельно были предприняты?

Comment: Для ANSI достаточно перебрать символы с ascii кодами от 32 до 126 через ::DrawText. Но в общем случае это неправильно, так как могу не знать какие коды имеет например германский алфавит и поддерживает ли его конкретный TTF шрифт.